# Postgres UPDATE: confusing value for column name

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11, string-constant

I have a postgres table `seq_data` that looks like this:

```
data_id | machine |     run      | cell  | run_start  | library |                   expected_dir                    | transferred | failed | cloud | csv_uploaded |         last_updated          
---------+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-------+--------------+-------------------------------
       1 | rsii_1  | RUN001     | B01_1 | 2020-02-05 | N/A      |                some/dir                            | t           | f      | t     | t            | 2020-02-07 11:24:17.279879+00
       2 | rsii_1  | RUN001     | C01_1 | 2020-02-05 | N/A      |                some/dir                            | t           | f      | t     | t            | 2020-02-07 11:24:17.279879+00
```

What I am trying to do is update the column library.

If i do:

```
data_monitor=> UPDATE seq_data SET failed=TRUE WHERE data_id=2;
UPDATE 1
```

It works and I get:

```
data_id | machine |     run      | cell  | run_start  | library |                   expected_dir                    | transferred | failed | cloud | csv_uploaded |         last_updated          
---------+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+--------+-------+--------------+-------------------------------
       1 | rsii_1  | RUN001     | B01_1 | 2020-02-05 | N/A      |                some/dir                            | t           | f      | t     | t            | 2020-02-07 11:24:17.279879+00
       2 | rsii_1  | RUN001     | C01_1 | 2020-02-05 | N/A      |                some/dir                            | t           | t      | t     | t            | 2020-02-07 11:24:17.279879+00
```

But when I do:

```
data_monitor=> UPDATE seq_data SET library=this_library WHERE data_id=1;
ERROR:  column "this_library" does not exist
LINE 1: UPDATE seq_data SET library=this_library WHERE data_id=1;
```

What I actually want to do is edit `library` based on `run`, `cell` and `machine`

```
data_monitor=> UPDATE seq_data SET library=this_library WHERE machine=rsii_1 and run=RUN001 and cell=B01_1;
ERROR:  column "rsii_1" does not exist
LINE 1: ...E seq_data SET library=this_library WHERE machine=rsii_1 and...
```

Why is this happening?

It seems like it is getting confused in `UPDATE seq_data SET library=this_library WHERE machine=rsii_1 and run=RUN001 and cell=B01_1;` skipping the column `library`, and thinking that the column name is actually the value, `this_library`

Version: postgresql-11

And this is how I created the table:

```
CREATE TABLE seq_data (
    data_id serial NOT NULL,
    machine varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    run varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    cell varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    run_start date NOT NULL,
    library varchar(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N/A',
    expected_dir varchar(100),
    transferred boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f',
    failed boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f',
    cloud boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f',
    csv_uploaded boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT 'f',
    last_updated timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    PRIMARY KEY (data_id),
    CONSTRAINT data_id UNIQUE (machine, run, cell)
);
```

### UPDATE

In Python3.7 using psycopg2

```
dbconn.query(
'''UPDATE seq_data
   SET library=%s
   WHERE run=%s and machine=%s and cell=%s;''',
   (sample_name[1], run, machine, sample_name[0],), commit=True)
```

How would I put quotes around these in python? All the variables are already strings.

Comment: String constants need to be surrounded by single quotes. `SET library = 'this_library'` https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS

Comment: you are very correct, I'm going to edit my question. I'm actually doing this using Python.

Comment: @DuDoff I don't know python but it should either be `SET library='%s'` or `SET library=\'%s\'`